# Is this image shows my strawberry plant have Leaf Scorch fungus infection?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, strawberries

I have brought new strawberry plants, they seem to have black dots even for green leaves. I can see a lot of dead leaves with these marks, is this a fungus infection?

[image]

Based on my research is Leaf scorch is caused by the fungus Diplocarpon earliana.

Will be great if anyone can confirm this or share any useful points.